# Creating timedelta column from a datetime64[ns] column which has NaT values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am reading in a CSV file.

```
df = pd.read_csv('xyz.csv',parse_dates=['last_time'])
```

The `dtype` of `last_tweeted` column is `datetime64[ns]`.

The column contains only `1 datetime64[ns]` rest are all `NaT` for now.

```
df

     last_time
0      NaT
1      NaT
2      NaT
3      NaT
4      2020-07-07 15:53:26.798844
```

I want to make a new column `time_since`.

```
df['time_since'] = df[df['last_time'] - datetime.datetime.now()]
```

I read through a bunch of questions but was unable to figure out the issue.

I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
> exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
> File "", line 1, in 
> df['trial'] = df[df['last_time'] - datetime.datetime.now()]
> File "/home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2806, in **getitem**
> indexer = self.loc._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis=1, raise_missing=True)[1]
> File "/home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1553, in _get_listlike_indexer
> keyarr, indexer, o._get_axis_number(axis), raise_missing=raise_missing
> File "/home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1640, in _validate_read_indexer
> raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
> KeyError: "None of [TimedeltaIndex([NaT, NaT, NaT, NaT, NaT, NaT, NaT, NaT,\n                '-1 days +23:06:31.564892', NaT, NaT],\n               dtype='timedelta64[ns]', freq=None)] are in the [columns]"

What am I doing wrong? I assumed that the `NaT`'s would be ignored for the calculation or I would get a `timedelta` column with a bunch of `NaT`'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `df[]`, it is used for [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) by some mask:

```
df['time_since'] = df['last_time'] - datetime.datetime.now()
```

Comment: Ah...there it is. I was using `.loc` earlier and forgot to recheck. Thanks Jezrael, as usual you are the expert!